# Show number of characters when typing

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, character-limit

I just edited my StackOverflow Profile, I pressed Save Profile, but it refused to save because I exceeded the maximum characters. In fact, while I was editing, I was looking for a character count, but didn't see one. I was afraid I'd go over, and sure enough, I did.

So why isn't there a character count when editing your profile, or even when typing a question like I am now? I would like to know *while I'm typing* if I've exceeded the maximum length, not after I press "Save" or "Post" etc. This applies to any place where you type large text with a size limit - even on all the different StackExchange sites.

Comment: Would be consistent with the rest of the site.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi All StackExchange sites for that matter

Comment: True, but I've been traumatized by a giant `S` in my youth.

Comment: I rolled back the edit because I intended it to be for any place where you type and there's a limit. Editing the profile was just the example that made me come here and request it.

Comment: I hope I don't get a +5 and a -2 or my rep will be 666...

Comment: HAHAHA For once I actually appreciate a downvoter - thanks for the 666 rep

Comment: Oh, and that's not a duplicate by the way. The solution which was done there is actually the problem I'm having now. I shouldn't get this alert *after* typing. People need to know before they click "Save" or "Post".

Comment: So, you really wrote more than 3,000 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character limit for answers and questions is 30,000 characters. This is a pretty huge block of text and good answers, howsoever detailed, are not expected to reach such lengths and rarely do. The same extends for questions. Hence, there really is no need for a live character count on the questions or answers page.

In fact, the number of posts longer than 1.5k on MSO [is pretty small](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/132831/post-length-versus-count#graph), with even fewer reaching the character limit. I have taken the example of MSO, as posts tend to be generally longer here than on other sites.

[image]

In the case of About Me's, the trend is similar. In fact, it is even more compacted with very few [HTML-rendered posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194609/200868) [exceeding the 3k character limit](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/130931/profile-length-versus-count#graph), meaning the number of people hitting the limit is even lesser than this graph suggests.

[image]

So, there doesnt really seem to be any need for this.

Comment: Even I have only reached the character limit for questions/answers *once*. And as any regular here on Meta can tell you, my answers are frequently tl;dr.

Comment: I guess I write too much, and while editing my profile I only added probably about 20-30 characters to what I have now when I hit that limit.

Comment: On [codereview.se] we require that the code to be reviewed should be contained within the question itself. Needless to say, it can be quite a lot of code. Which is why I am down-voting this.